# Не работает прокрутка снизу вверх, сверху вниз работает нормально

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

```
 // Scroll to corresponding content with an offset
         var contentOffset = $('.dishes .child-category-name').eq(index).offset().top;
         var scrollPosition = contentOffset - $('.child-category-name').offset().top - 345;
         $('html, body').animate({
             scrollTop: scrollPosition
         }, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас результат `scrollPosition` вычисляется как разница между `contentOffset` и текущим положением прокрутки минус некоторый фиксированный сдвиг в `345`. Если текущее положение прокрутки находится выше, чем `contentOffset`, то `scrollPosition` станет отрицательным. Когда Вы пытаетесь выполнить прокрутку с отрицательным значением `scrollTop`, браузер игнорирует эту команду, так как она не имеет смысла — невозможно прокрутить ниже текущего начального положения, которое уже находится в самом верху.